# How to use write.table in R with up/down-arrows?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got a dataframe `f` in R with one column called `utterance` which contains lines with character strings like:

- `~↑I don't think I can↑~` and
- `↓carrying↓`

Whenever I'm using

```
write.table(f, "C:/Users/...txt", sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

to create a table in a `.txt`, Up and Down arrows are given like so in the created `.txt` file:

- `<U+2191>` instead of the actual `↑`
- `<U+2193>` instead of the actual `↓`
- `~<U+2191>I don't think I can<U+2191>~`
- `<U+2193>carrying<U+2193>`

How can I fix this problem to get the actual `↑` and `↓` in the `txt` files by using the correct settings for `write.table` in R? I'm using the standard text editor of Windows10 and Notepad++.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question and share a [mcve] (are `↑↓` arrows hard-coded, or where the `x` variable comes from?)

Answer (score 0):

There are some advices in the [Escaping from character encoding hell in R on Windows](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/escaping-from-character-encoding-hell-in-r-on-windows/) (and all other known articles on this topic) however those do not seem to be useful for this particular case as the `↑` and `↓` characters do not come under any *natural* language.

### Good news

[Write file as UTF-8 encoding in R for Windows](https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/)

> … when the R writes a UTF-8 text into a file on Windows, characters of
> unsupported language are modified. In contrast, all characters are
> written correctly in Mac OS.
>
> **Using binary**
>
> There is a solution for this problem. Writing a binary file instead of
> a text file solves this. All applications handling a UTF-8 file in
> Windows are using the same trick.
>
> **BOM**
>
> The BOM should not be used in UTF-8 files.  This is what the Linux and
> the Mac OS are doing. But the Windows Notepad and some applications
> use the BOM. So, handling the BOM is needed, in spite of grammatically
> wrong.
>
> …

### Solution

**arrows.html** (a sample UTF-8 file, used later in `70166451.r`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> </head>
    <body>up=&#x2191;  ↑↓  down=&#x2193;</body>
</html>
```

**70166451.r** (partially commented script):

```
###                  my circumstances
setwd("D:\\BAT\\R")    
filepath = '70166451.txt'

### ↓↓↓ adapted from https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/
BOM <- charToRaw('\xEF\xBB\xBF')
writeUtf8 <- function(xstr, filepath, forappend=F, bom=F) {
  openmode <- ifelse(forappend, 'ab', 'wb')
  con <- file( filepath, open=openmode)
  if( !forappend && bom ) writeBin(BOM, con, endian="little")
  # If the connection is open it is written from its current position:
  writeBin(charToRaw(xstr), con, endian="little")
  close(con)
}
###  ↑↑↑ adapted from https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/

### hard-coded characters ↑ and ↓
aa <- "up ↑ (↑↓) ↓ down"                      # unworkable? (not solved)
aa <- "up \u2191 (↑↓) \u2193 down"            # unworkable! (unsolvable?)
aa <- "up \u2191 (\u2191\u2193) \u2193 down"  #   workable! (solved here)
# print( c( 'aa ', Encoding(aa), aa ))
# "aa "   "UTF-8"   "up <U+2191> (<U+2191><U+2193>) <U+2193> down"

xx <- data.frame( myword = c(aa,toupper(aa)), word = c(toupper(aa),aa))
yy <- readr::format_tsv( xx, append = F, quote_escape = "none", eol = "\r\n")
writeUtf8( yy, filepath)

### characters read from a file 
library(xml2)
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("arrows.html", encoding='utf-8'), collapse=" ")
aaa <- xml_text(read_html(charToRaw(rawHTML)))
# print( c( 'aaa', Encoding(aaa), aaa ))
# "aaa"   "UTF-8"   "up=<U+2191>  <U+2191><U+2193>  down=<U+2193>"

xxx <- data.frame( myword = c(aaa,toupper(aaa)), word = c(toupper(aaa),aaa))
yyy <- readr::format_tsv( xxx, append = T, quote_escape = "none", eol = "\r\n")
writeUtf8( yyy, filepath, forappend=T)
```

**Result** (one can *Copy*&*Paste* above code snippet to an open *R Console* window, or save and run using `Rscript.exe` as shown below):

```
pushd D:\bat\R & del 70166451*.txt & rscript 70166451.r & type 70166451*.txt & popd
```

> ```
> 70166451.txt
>
>
> myword  word
> up ↑ (↑↓) ↓ down        UP ↑ (↑↓) ↓ DOWN
> UP ↑ (↑↓) ↓ DOWN        up ↑ (↑↓) ↓ down
> up=↑  ↑↓  down=↓        UP=↑  ↑↓  DOWN=↓
> UP=↑  ↑↓  DOWN=↓        up=↑  ↑↓  down=↓
> ```